# Passing function call to $(document).ready causes variable to be NaN

Tags: javascript, nan, var

Why does this code return `spentScores` as NaN?

```js
$(document).ready(initScores());

var lvlScores = 0;
var currentScores = 0;
var spentScores = 0;

function initScores() {
  console.log(spentScores);
  console.log(spentScores + 44);
  console.log(lvlScores);
  initLvlScores();
  initSpentScores();
  initCurrentScores();
}

function recountLvlScores() {
  initScores();
  clearStatistics();
}

function initLvlScores() {
  var lvl = parseInt($('.lvl-select').val());
  switch (lvl) {
    case 1:
      lvlScores = 1000;
      break;
    case 2:
      lvlScores = 1200;
      break;
    case 3:
      lvlScores = 1500;
      break;
    case 4:
      lvlScores = 2000;
      break;
    case 5:
      lvlScores = 3000;
      break;
  }
}

function initSpentScores() {
  $('.statistics').each(function() {
    console.log("!!" + spentScores + parseInt($(this).val()));
    console.log("!!" + parseInt($(this).val()));
    spentScores = spentScores + parseInt($(this).val());
  });
}

function initCurrentScores() {
  currentScores = lvlScores - spentScores;
  $('.scores').html(currentScores);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Console:

```
scoresEditCounting.js:9 undefined
scoresEditCounting.js:10 NaN
scoresEditCounting.js:11 undefined
scoresEditCounting.js:40 !!undefined44
scoresEditCounting.js:41 !!44
scoresEditCounting.js:40 !!NaN44
scoresEditCounting.js:41 !!44
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript at the bottom of the page, when the `document` is already `ready`?

Comment: Yes, because // console.log("!!" + parseInt($(this).val())); returns "!!44"

Comment: where is the HTML elements

Comment: On the JSP page

Comment: What happens when you move the document.ready to the bottom of the code, or at least after your variable declarations? edit: Your problem may be that the functions are all being called before the variables are assigned values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update this line:

```
$(document).ready(initScores());
```

To this:

```
$(document).ready(initScores);
```

You want the page the call the function when it is ready. Otherwise you are trying to access DOM elements before the page is ready.

Comment: That's not it. It is executing given his console log is running

Comment: @Orpheus It's executing _early_

Comment: @Orpheus It is getting an element from the DOM before the page is ready. So it causes it to fail

Comment: Thank's! It seems that works! But why? what is the difference?

Comment: When you use `parenthesis()` the function is called right away. What you want is assign the function definition to the event handler, and it will be called when the event is triggered. That is the difference.